# Allow window to dynamically resize after transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the issue:

We can get the window to resize according to the content, but when the window is resized the height does not change dynamically either leaving a ton of white space below or hiding the content behind the rest of the page.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="panel-container" style="height: 706px;">
   <div class="control-panel create-job flexible">
     <div class="column-container">
```

JSX:

```
  resizePanel: function (height) {
   this.refs.panel.style.height = height + 'px';
  },
  getPanelContainerStyle: function (controlPanel) {
    if (this.state.isPanelOpen && _.isObject(controlPanel)) {
      var height = controlPanel.type.prototype.height;
      if (_.isNumber(height)) {
       return {height: height};
      } else return {height: 100};
    } else return {};
  },
```

CSS:

```
 .panel-container
   height 0
   transition height 0.3s
   margin-top bump-lg px
   margin-bottom bump-lg px
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using viewport units? you can find more information in here https://teamtreehouse.com/community/resizing-div-automatically-depending-on-screen-size

Comment: I have not, but I'm going to give this a shot with "max-height" first to see if we can make that cooperate.

Comment: I just tried this out but it didn't work for this scenario. Thanks for the suggestion though!